# Prove or Disprove $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that satisfy the following conditions:
-for every $y\ne0,\lim_{x\to0}f(x,y)\ne f(0,y)$
-for every $x\ne0,\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)\ne f(x,0)$
-$f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
Prove or Disprove:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}f(x,y)$$
and find $f$ that satisfy the conditions above

I've tried to set $f$ to be
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&x=0,y\ne0\\
-1&x\ne0,y=0\\
\frac{xy}{1+xy}&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
I am not sure if it disprove the question.

Comment: Why in the world would you type nine characters to get $\text{-1}$ instead of two characters to get $-1,$ when a minus sign and not a hyphen was appropriate? I've fixed that and some other MathJax usage absurdities.

Comment: Your function is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Hint on the prove/disprove: suppose $\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y) \neq f(0,0)$, then there exists a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $|f(0,0) - \lim_{y \to 0} f(x_n,y) | > \epsilon$ for some fixed $\epsilon$. On the other hand, you can find a sequence $(y_{n,m})_m$ such that $f(x_{n}, y_{n,m}) \to \lim_{y \to 0} f(x_n,y)$. What does this tell you about the continuity of $f$ at the origin?

Comment: @WillieWong why my function is not continuous at the origin?the limit is 0 no?

Comment: @WillieWong i didn't manage to prove or disprove can you help me?

Comment: A **necessary** consequence of $f$ being continuous at $(0,0)$ is that $\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) = f(0,0)$.  For your function the limit $= 1$ while $f(0,0) = 0$.  // How far have you gotten based on my previous hint?